# How would I use a while true loop in this?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm making a program and it needs a while loop to repeat a process. I don't really understand while loops, and the demonstrations online don't really help with my situation.

```
while true:
    if password == 1526:
        typewriter ("ACCESS GRANTED")

else:
    typewriter ("ACCESS DENIED")
    typewriter ("You must enter the password correctly to proceed. ")

    typewriter ("Please input password: ")
    password = int(input (""))
```

Comment: you want loop to run always?

Comment: yes, until the user inputs the code correctly

Comment: Check the answer i posted below

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is, you want to prompt for entering password until input/password is 1256.

```
while True:
    typewriter("Please input password: ")
    password = int(input ("")) 

    if password == 1526:
        typewriter ("ACCESS GRANTED")
        break
    else:
        typewriter ("ACCESS DENIED")
        typewriter ("You must enter the password correctly to proceed. ")
```